# Are GTM event names automatically tracked in GA4?

Tags: events, configuration, tags, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to wrap my head around GTM Tags and how they work in GA4.

For example I have this GTM tag that fires when a button is clicked. This is working and I can see the event fire in the GA4 debug view.

1. If I did nothing else would I be able to see the event count of *map_grid_view* without registering a custom dimension? (I know the event parameters would not show)
2. If i registered *click_text* and *page_path* as custom dimensions then re-used those event parameters in other events I created would that data pull automatically into GA4 once i published my GTM container? (Is this approach considered best practice?)

[image: GTM tag configuration screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. You don't need to register the event name
2. Yes. It's a best practice if you can re-use them. Since free version of GA4 only allow us to register 50 custom dimensions and metrics. If the tracking strategy go complicated in the future. The quota is not enough then.